# Custom context variables in antlr4 visitor in javascript

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4, visitor-pattern

I want to replace variables in an input with it's value from javascript variables. It's possible that the variable name is a path of an object with functions in the middle or at the end: `object.property.someFunction().propertyOfFunctionResult`.

The grammar for this looks like:

```
funParameter: '(' value? (', ' value)*  ')' ;
value: INT | BOOL | STRING | variable;
varname: VAR ;
variable: (varname | '{' value '}') funParameter? ('.' variable)* ;
```

The visitor-function for `variable` (everything involving `customValue` is just how I would imagine how to do it):

```
visitVariable(ctx) {
  var key, val;
  if(ctx.value()) {
    key = this.visit(ctx.value());
  } else if(ctx.varname()) {
    key = ctx.varname().getText();
  }
  if(ctx.funParameter()) {
    //idea:
    val = this.callFunction(key, this.visit(ctx.funParameter()), ctx.customValue); //pass value to function call
  } else {
    //idea:
    if(ctx.customValue) {
      val = ctx.customValue[key]; //Get value from parent
    } else {
      val = this.vars[key]; //Get value from JS-variables
    }
  }
  if(ctx.variable()) {
     //idea:
    val = this.visit(ctx.variable(), {customValue:val});
  } 
  return val;
}
```

The problem is, that I don't know how to pass the current value of the JS-variable down the parse tree. When `object` is evaluated I would need to pass the JS-object in the visitor down so that in the next `visitVariable`  it's clear that I want to return the value of `object.property`.
Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably kind of hacked, but the function `getParent()`, that is described in the docs, was not available in the `ctx`-object. But I found `ctx.parentCtx`. Now I'm just assigning `ctx.customValue = 'somevalue'` and can access it from the children with `ctx.parentCtx.customValue`.